# Is there any way of creating dynamic index on cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter

This query needs to create index on firebase but it is creating index on the specific values of `widget.group`. Now `widget.group` can have any value. Is there any way creating composite dynamic index.

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('chat')
        .doc('${widget.group}')
        .collection('${widget.group}')
        .where('idTo', isEqualTo: '${widget.currentUserId}')
        .orderBy('timestamp')
        .limitToLast(1)
        .get();
```

I tried below but it is not working

```
chat    timestamp Descending idTo Ascending Collection group        Enabled
```

Comment: Hi. When you say "it is not working", what do you mean? Did you get an error message?

Comment: Yes it needs to create index for each widget.group which is not possible as they are dynamic